# How to make the same query for every result of another query

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery

I currently have defined a view such as this one

```
CREATE VIEW top10 as
(
SELECT distinct ternary.id_skill, skill.name_skill, ranking_skill, ternary.id_profile, profile.name_profile
FROM ternary
INNER JOIN skill
ON skill.id_skill=ternary.id_skill 
INNER JOIN profile
ON profile.id_profile=ternary.id_profile
WHERE ternary.id_profile= 1
GROUP BY ternary.id_skill
ORDER BY ternary.ranking_skill DESC
LIMIT 10 
)
UNION
(
SELECT distinct ternary.id_skill, skill.name_skill, ranking_skill, ternary.id_profile, profile.name_profile
FROM ternary
INNER JOIN skill
ON skill.id_skill=ternary.id_skill 
INNER JOIN profile
ON profile.id_profile=ternary.id_profile
WHERE ternary.id_profile= 2
GROUP BY ternary.id_skill
ORDER BY ternary.ranking_skill DESC
LIMIT 10 
)
UNION
(
........
)
```

As you can see the View is simply doing Union between N queries, and all are identical except the query a different `id_profile` and each give me the top 10 for each profile, from the first to the last, up to 22 right now. Once defined I query the view as I was doing previously, for example with a

```
select * from top10
```

or `insert way more complex query here`

Now I want to make this same solution work without hard coding the profiles in the view, because more profiles could be added, or even change. Because of that I built the following query, which I would like to replace the previous View with, but it does not give identical results, so I am looking for a proper SQL way of doing this, as I said, dynamically, without the query being affected by how many profiles are defined.

```
SELECT distinct ternary.id_skill, skill.name_skill, ranking_skill, ternary.id_profile, profile.name_profile
FROM ternary
INNER JOIN skill
ON skill.id_skill=ternary.id_skill 
INNER JOIN profile
ON profile.id_profile=ternary.id_profile
WHERE ternary.id_profile IN (SELECT id_profile from profile)
GROUP BY ternary.id_skill
ORDER BY ternary.ranking_skill DESC
LIMIT 10;
```

Tables definition in case they are useful:

```
CREATE TABLE profile (
        id_profile VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL,
        name_profile VARCHAR(200),
        type_profile VARCHAR(200),
        PRIMARY KEY (id_profile)
    );


CREATE TABLE ternary (
    id_oferta VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL,
    id_skill VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL,
    id_profile VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL,
    ranking_skill DOUBLE NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id_oferta, id_skill, id_profile),
    FOREIGN KEY (id_oferta) REFERENCES oferta(id_oferta),
    FOREIGN KEY (id_skill) REFERENCES skill(id_skill),
    FOREIGN KEY (id_profile) REFERENCES profile(id_profile)
);
```

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: Do you want 10 unique records from each profile id?

Comment: @Gaj Yes that's what I want and since I was having an awful lot of trouble getting it, and even more complexity implementing it in Java, after a lot of pain I opted for a simpler solution and this view was born. Now I would like to improve it by not needing 22 unions in a view, even thought it perform okay for the requirements.

Comment: @Strawberry I gave the creation of the two relevant tables and relevant queries and even a solution I attempted... If you tell me what I can improve in a more specific way I can do it, but as far as I see from that post, only thing I would be missing is point number 2, and that I attempt to explain in plain English... Seems harsh to downvote as if the question is not providing info, if that was the reason

Comment: @gaj I misspoke. I meant to say that I want 10 unique record from each profile id, but not random, I want the top 10 of each separated one. That's why I use the field ranking to order it

Comment: As mentioned, it's nice to see three things.

Comment: BTW, it's not at all 'harsh'. We have only 3 tools at our disposal to register dissatisfaction with a given question: downvote, close, and comment. Of these it's my impression that downvoting is the most effective method of improving question quality. Remember, votes are reversible.

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
SELECT ternary.id_skill, 
        skill.name_skill, 
        ranking_skill, 
        ternary.id_profile, 
        profile.name_profile
FROM ternary
        INNER JOIN skill ON skill.id_skill=ternary.id_skill 
        INNER JOIN profile ON profile.id_profile=ternary.id_profile
WHERE (ternary.id_profile, ternary.id_skill) in (Select distinct id_profile, id_skill From ternary where id_profile between 1 and 22)
ORDER BY ternary.ranking_skill DESC
```

Note: I have assumed required id_profile is 1 to 22. if its not like that then change that

Comment: What if the profile's IDs are not linear? Like, not as easy as small Ints? If id_1=365 and id_2=386 and id_3=517, because they were created using a hash in another part of the development

Comment: It's a good idea, I will try to incorporate it to my query, but as of right now, it gives me thousands of results, instead of 10*22 = 220. If I try to put a limit, since it would be in a subquery, I get the following error: ERROR 1235 (42000): This version of MySQL doesn't yet support 'LIMIT & IN/ALL/ANY/SOME subquery'